# Add a custom button to Customers Grid

Tags: plugin, magento2.1.5, customer-grid

I am trying to add a custom button to the Customers Grid but I have not been able to do it using a di.xml

[image]

Anyone available to point me in the right direction?

Comment: You can add  button using ui component xml

Comment: Hi @PramodKharade, I don't want to do it that way because then other modules cannot add buttons dynamically without taking my ui_component xml file into consideration.